# How to validate Apache Beam command line arguments

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I used the apache beam Python SDK to create a command line program to launch Dataflow jobs on Google Cloud. Then when using it, I messed up one of the options. I messed it up like this `--otiopn value`, not like this `--option laevu`. When an invalid option is specified, I'd expect the program to die or at least warn the user. Instead my program launched a Dataflow job using the default for `--option` and I didn't notice until completion.

How can I use apache beam to validate my command line arguments and avoid situations like this?

Comment: That is not an apache beam problem really. This is more of a *parameter/argument handling* problem for your code. Use python's `argparse` module if you like and create checks for it. You can find a lot of tutorials on how to do it. But to get you started, here is a [link](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params)

Comment: I've looked into the [relevant code](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/options/pipeline_options.py) some. Apache beam already uses `argparse` to parse the command line. To allow users to supply command line arguments without including them in a `PipelineOptions` object they ignore all unexpected options, I guess assuming you'll handle those yourself. What I was looking for was an option to turn that off, but it doesn't look like there's a way.

Comment: Sadly, as far as I know there is no way at the current moment to do that. Sorry that I was not able to provide a helpful way to solve your problem. But things you could do instead would be to : log all activities and processes occurring in your system and to test arguments passed. Both are vital for security and enterprise level coding and skills you definitely should develop towards.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody still has this question, it is now indeed possible to have Beam validate arguments.

Create your own custom options that extends PipelineOptions or one of its implementations and use the @Required annotation for required arguments.

```
public interface MyCustomOptions extends PipelineOptions {

@Description("Pub/Sub subscription name")
@Validation.Required
String getSubscriptionName();
void setSubscriptionName(String value);

}
```

Then in your Beam pipeline, create your options as follows:

```
PipelineOptionsFactory.register(MyCustomOptions.class);
MyCustomOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(MyCustomOptions.class);
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
...
p.run();
```

If the option subscriptionName is not defined at runtime, Beam will throw an IllegalArgumentException with a message like this:

> Missing required value for [--subscriptionName, "Pub/Sub subscription name"].